# SSIS package to load XLSX to SQL fails when run in Agent with Unexpected Termination

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, xlsx, sql-agent

Let me start by saying I've read just about everything on 'Unexpected Termination' errors the last few days and am none the wiser!

I have a number of XLSX files in a network folder, and have 2 packages in a project to read them and load to SQL server (2017) using Excel connector (ACE.16) on dev and prod.

One package loops through about 35 workbooks and appends them all to a single SQL table.
The second package simply reads a single (~5mb) file and writes to a SQL table (with a single data transformation along the way - its not that, I removed it and it still failed)

Both packages use same source folder.
Both packages write to same destination DB.
Both packages run fine on my local machine.
Both packages can be executed correctly from the SSISDB catalog on the server (Right-click-->Execute).

When scheduled in Agent (we have a proxy account with correct folder permissions) the looping package runs just fine, whilst the simpler package fails with 'Unexpected Termination'
Verbose logging reveals nothing, as does Event Viewer on the SQL box.

I started to look into other options such as converting to CSV first using Script Task and Excel Interop but we are a 365 site now so we'd need Office client installs on dev and production server (and not knowing much C# won't help!)

My next route is to see if I can get it to write to CSV destination successfully.  If so then I might be able to go XLSX-->CSV-->SQL without having to use Interop or external libraries.

Unfortunately I've not been able to turn up anything further in my searches, so wondered if someone more enlightened than me might be able to suggest where to look next.